# Start typing in a TextInput from right not left (React-Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styling, arabic

I have a react-native application, and I was wondering if I can change the cursor where the user can start typing from right to left instead from left to right.

I have a Boolean where I can check if the app is in right to left or left to right `isRTL()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work by just adding the `textAlign: 'right'` styling property.

Comment: hey this partially solved the problem, when I type in english it starts from the left and the cursor is at the left, but when I type in arabic the cursor is still on the left but when I type it becomes on the left ?. So how do I reposition Also the cursor to the right ?

Comment: Hey I found this issue on Github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10812. Hopefully this can help you to solve your problem because I don't know any other way to do it.